# FindControl cannot find checkbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have checkboxes created in a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="companyRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class ="DGItemStyle" id="myresultsRow1" runat="server" style='<%# SetBoxVisibilityReverse(Eval("compnName1").ToString()) %>'> 
            <td  style="padding:0.5em;"><%#Eval("compnAddress1") %></td> 
            .....
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="foo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" name="foo" /></td>
        </tr>
```

I want to find out which checkbox is currently selected by user, so in the codebehind I do:

```
CheckBox chkbox_All = FindControl("foo") as CheckBox;
if (chkbox_All != null)
{
   if (!chkbox_All.Checked)
   {
       Response.Write("No checked");
   }
   else
   {
       var IDs = chkbox_All.ClientID;
       Response.Write("ID here...");
   }
}
```

But what I found is that the `chkbox_All` is always null no matter how many checkboxes are selected.
Why is it so and how could I find which checkbox is checked in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enumerate through `companyRepeater.Items` using a `foreach` block as below

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in companyRepeater.Items)
{
    CheckBox chkbox_All = ri.FindControl("foo") as CheckBox;
    if (chkbox_All != null)
    {
       if (!chkbox_All.Checked)
       {
           Response.Write("No checked");
       }
       else
       {
           var IDs = chkbox_All.ClientID;
           Response.Write("ID here...");
       }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to display the ID of the checked checkboxes, add a [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) somewhere outside the repeater

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltChecked" runat="server" />
```

and add the id to `ltChecked.Text` if the checkbox is checked

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in companyRepeater.Items)
{
    CheckBox chkbox_All = ri.FindControl("foo") as CheckBox;
    if (chkbox_All != null)
    {
       if (chkbox_All.Checked)
       {
           ltChecked.Text += chkbox_All.ClientID;
           ltChecked.Text += ", ";
       }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

To prevent the page reload when checking the checkbox, remove `AutoPostBack="True"` from the `foo` checkbox

```
<asp:Repeater ID="companyRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class = "DGItemStyle"  id="myresultsRow1" runat="server" style='<%# SetBoxVisibilityReverse(Eval("compnName1").ToString()) %>'> 
            <td  style="padding:0.5em;"><%#Eval("compnAddress1") %></td> 
            .....
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="foo" runat="server" name="foo" /></td>
        </tr>
```

**EDIT 3**

To get the `compnName1` value from the same row as the checked checkbox, add a hidden field (`hdCompName`) that holds the `compnName1` value in the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="companyRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class = "DGItemStyle"  id="myresultsRow1" runat="server" style='<%# SetBoxVisibilityReverse(Eval("compnName1").ToString()) %>'> 
            <td  style="padding:0.5em;"><%#Eval("compnAddress1") %></td> 
            .....
            <td><asp:CheckBox id="foo" runat="server" name="foo" />
                <asp:HiddenField id="hdCompName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("compnName1") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

then get the value of `hdCompName` in the code behind as below

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in companyRepeater.Items)
{
    CheckBox chkbox_All = ri.FindControl("foo") as CheckBox;
    if (chkbox_All != null)
    {
        if (chkbox_All.Checked)
        {
            HiddenField hdCompName = ri.FindControl("hdCompName") as HiddenField;
            ltChecked.Text += hdCompName.Value;
            ltChecked.Text += ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats right! Then do you know how could I identify which checkbox is checked?

Comment: How to display that ID? I cannot use message box.

Comment: You can use a [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) outside of the repeater and set the `Text` property to the ID of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: You mean : chkbox_All.ClientID.text ?

Comment: Thank you! Btw, everytime I check a checkbox the page reload, is there any way to prevent it ?

Comment: It's because of `AutoPostBack="True"`, you need to remove it as in the EDIT 2 section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and advise, I ll choose it as perfect answer to my question! Could I ask if it is possible to get the value "Eval("compnName1").ToString()" of the row where the checkbox checked?

Comment: Yes it's possible, use a hidden field as described in EDIT 3 section.

Comment: I added namespace: using System.Web.UI.WebControls; but have error using Hidden field: "httpparseexception was unhadled by user code" System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:HiddenField' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField'.

Comment: Did you change your repeater code exactly as the code in EDIT 3 section?

Comment: Yes, my mistake! All your solutions are precise and works perfectly, thanks a mil!!